# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (34,) and (12,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to plot time-series. But I have the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (34,12)`

I'm stacking to reshaping the image. How should I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from  mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
print("Reading in the data from the netCDF file")
filename = "C:/Users/zayam/Downloads/python_lesson/LAI_mean_monthly_1981-2015.nc4" 
data = Dataset(filename)
print("Setting the variable from the data")
lai = data.variables['LAI'][:] 
ntimes, nlat, nlon = np.shape(lai)
print("The temp array has dimensions: \n"
      "Time (number of years x 12 months): {}\n"
      "Latitudes: {}\n"
      "Longitudes: {}".format(ntimes, nlat, nlon)
      )
print("Calculating the average across all years")
lai_av_1981_2015 = np.mean(lai[:,:,:], axis = 0)
print("Plotting a global map")
plt.figure()
map = Basemap(projection="cyl", resolution='c', llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180) 
map.drawcoastlines(color="black")
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(data.variables['lon'][:], data.variables['lat'][:]) 
x,y = map(lons, lats)
lai_plot = map.contourf(x, y, lai_av_1981_2015, cmap=plt.cm.viridis) 
cb = map.colorbar(lai_plot, "bottom", size="5%", pad="2%", extend = 'both')
cb.set_label("LAI") 
plt.title("Mean LAI (1981-2015)")
plt.show() 
print("Calculating the global average")
global_average = np.mean(lai[:,:,:], axis=(1,2))
print("Calculating the annual average")
annual_lai = np.mean(np.reshape(global_average, (34,12)), axis = 1)
print("Calculate the 1981-1990 average")
av_1981_1990 = np.mean(annual_lai[80:89])
print("Calculate the lai anomaly compared to the 1981-1990 average")
lai_anomaly = annual_lai - av_1981_1990
# Plot 2 - Timeseries
print("Plotting a time series graph")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(1981,2015), lai_anomaly) 
plt.ylim(np.floor(min(lai_anomaly)), np.ceil(max(lai_anomaly))) 
plt.title("Global Average LAI Anomaly (1981-2015)")
plt.xlabel("Years") # label for the x axis
plt.ylabel("Difference from 1981-1990 average") 
plt.show()
```

Error Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-99-e2d53fc7b62c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/zayam/OneDrive/Documents/python_lesson/plot_cru-ts_examples.py', wdir='C:/Users/zayam/OneDrive/Documents/python_lesson')

  File "C:\Users\zayam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\zayam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/zayam/OneDrive/Documents/python_lesson/plot_cru-ts_examples.py", line 32, in <module>
    annual_lai = np.mean(np.reshape(global_average, (34,12)), axis = 1)

  File "C:\Users\zayam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 292, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\zayam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 56, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\zayam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 4591, in reshape
    result = self._data.reshape(*s, **kwargs).view(type(self))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (34,12)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback and add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code depends on local files that we don't have access to, so we can't reproduce your issue. Also try to keep dependencies to a minimum. Since you are asking a Numpy related question, try to not include any dependencies beyond Numpy itself.

Comment: @a_guest I added the full traceback. Sorry for the understandable codes.

Comment: What is `lai.shape`?

Comment: Actually, now that I look more at it I think this is a big XY problem.  Is `lai` a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: @Zaya Apparently `global_average` is a one-dimensional array with 12 elements and that obviously can't be reshaped into an array of shape `(34,12)`. How did you choose this specific shape anyway?

Comment: @a_guest I saw one example of how to extract NetCDF file. and I tried in another files. This is the example: https://help.ceda.ac.uk/article/4728-cru-data-python-example#plot2

Comment: @DanielF yes my problem is plot XY. LAI is the leaf area index that I can choose from the data variables of the datasets.

Comment: @Zaya Okay so they have chosen some (arbitrary) numbers that fit for their example, you need to adjust them to fit your own data. Apparently they don't.